# PHP setlocale, UTF-8 or not?

Tags: php, localization, internationalization, locale, setlocale

I've installed `zh_TW` locale via

```
sudo locale-gen --purge en_US.UTF-8 zh_TW
```

And it codeset is **BIG5**

```
locale: zh_TW           directory: /usr/lib/locale/zh_TW
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    title | Chinese locale for Taiwan R.O.C.
    email | bug-glibc-locales@gnu.org
 language | Chinese
territory | Taiwan R.O.C.
 revision | 0.2
     date | 2000-08-02
  codeset | BIG5
```

And I've a simple PHP script

```
<?php

putenv('LC_ALL=zh_TW');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'zh_TW');
bindtextdomain("myPHPApp", "./locale");
textdomain("myPHPApp");

echo gettext("hello");
```

I have prepared a mo file (which is in **UTF8**) and put under the

```
./locale/zh_TW/LC_MESSAGES/myPHPApp.mo
```

And the `echo` did work, so, what is the point of installing locale such as **zh_TW.UTF-8**

Comment: There isn't any reason to `setlocale` if you've set it in your environment already, well, kind of. There are some categories that still need it if you use them: http://us2.php.net//manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Comment: What version of PHP you are using?

Answer (score 2):

> *What is the point of installing locale such as zh_TW.UTF-8?*

The point of the `.[codeset]` suffix in locale specification is to specify a codeset. If, for a particular language, `UTF-8` is a default codeset, you don't have to specify it explicitly - you are good with specifying just `zh_TW` (but you could also specify `zh_TW.UTF-8`). If you have console available, you can list the available locale by `locale -a`.

**But please note that this can be system specific!** While [on linux zh_TW is UTF-8 by default](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Table_of_locales), [on 
IBM it will be BIG5](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/txformp/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.cics.te.doc%2Ferziad0058.htm) and on Windows CP950!

Comment: Actually I am using Ubuntu, with `locale -a` I see zh_TW is BIG5, and the reason I ask is why I am using UTF8 in the mo file and it also work with the above code example.

Comment: @Howard it is strange inconsistency that `locale -a` says BIG5 and you say the files are for UTF-8. Anyway, you might be using both, as in this installation: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/localeconf/+question/130696.

Comment: no, `locale -a` say the installed locale is BIG5, but I say my mo file is UTF8 becoz it is prepared by me. My understanding is as my installed `zh_TW` is in BIG5, so when I use a UTF8 mo file, it should NOT work, but the thing is now it work, that is the confusing point.

Answer (score 2):

According to my understanding for Chinese language, there is two different version for each of them which is simplified and traditional Chinese language. By specifying zh_TW probably is to display traditional Chinese characters on your webpage. Since UTF-8 is defined in your header and by default it supports both of the chinese language, hence it is not necessary to to install them anymore.

*Additional information - if I'm not mistaken, you got to set the Locale of zh_TW if the Chinese character are going to store somewhere in the database.

Hope this helps.